# How to add new relation in many to many relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create lists that are edited by many users. So I go with many to many relations like this.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :editabilities, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :editable_lists, :through => :editabilities, :source => :list
end

class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :editabilities, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :editors, :through => :editabilities, :source => :user
end

class Editability < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And I add a editor for a list by like this.

```
u = User.first
l = List.first
Editability.create(user_id: u.id, list_id: l.id)
```

It seems to be working. But I'm not sure whether I am doing in a right way or wrong way. Is this a right way to do?

Comment: for many to many relation you need to use has_many_through or has_and_belongs_t0_many

Comment: I googled with "has_many_through" but, I only found information for "has_many :through". Can you give me document for it?

Comment: please check
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html
http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also:

```
u = User.first
l = List.first
u.editable_lists << l
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference

Comment: Thanks, It looks much better to use id directory.